# How to call native code without native modules with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to access native iOS or Android APIs through JavaScript without having to write a native module?

I cannot find a way of doing this.
I know that `NativeScript` has a clean interface for this, and it's very convenient,
is there any native modules that allow the same thing?

Comment: U can read the react native doc related to native module may be its helpfull u https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

Comment: But doesn't that involve creating a native module?